# Tensorflow tf.switch_case not working with keras Input

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I want to use tf.switch_case to be able to redirect learning flow for different branchs of the network using inputs however tf.switch_case does not work with Keras.Tensor ...

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
def f1(): return tf.constant(17)
def f2(): return tf.constant(31)
def f3(): return tf.constant(-1)
t_input = Input(shape=(1,), name="t_input")
r = tf.switch_case(t_input, branch_fns={0: f1, 1: f2}, default=f3)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-9-bd285228541c>", line 5, in <module>
    r = tf.switch_case(t_input, branch_fns={0: f1, 1: f2}, default=f3)
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3616, in switch_case
    return _indexed_case_helper(branch_fns, default, branch_index, name)
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3315, in _indexed_case_helper
    branch_fns, default, branch_index)
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3249, in _indexed_case_verify_and_canonicalize_args
    type(branch_index)))
TypeError: branch_index must a Tensor, got <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you'd do this in a Keras model. But just be careful when using these. For example, I'm not sure how well tested these are (for gradient flowing) if your `f1` `f2` are defining models in them. Nonetheless, you can do the following.

1. Define your input as `int32` type. Because `tf.switch_case` expects `int32`.
2. Make sure you define `batch_shape` and not `shape`, so that you can index the input tensor to get the scalar value to be passed to `tf.switch_case`.
3. Wrap the `tf.switch_case` in a `Lambda` layer.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda

def f1(): return tf.constant(17)
def f2(): return tf.constant(31)
def f3(): return tf.constant(-1)

t_input = Input(batch_shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name="t_input")

r = Lambda(lambda x: tf.switch_case(x[0], branch_fns={0: f1, 1: f2}, default=f3))(t_input)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=t_input, outputs=r)
```

Using it

```
print(model.predict([1]))
```

Returns

```
31
```

Comment: I want to use tf.switch_case to train only part of the network depending on the t_input value like in here : https://gist.github.com/Vaunorage/2fefd74e5bbcfcd6effac3888ce4f7ee. However it still does not work when layers are used instead of functions ...

Comment: @TahaMahjoubi, can you maybe create another question with exactly what you're trying to do? Almost always, when scaling from the toy problem to the real-world problem, there are new issues.

Comment: Yes I did here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67065868/training-different-branches-of-model-network-with-tf-switch-case. Thank you !