# Training different branches of model network with tf.switch_case

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I want to create a neural network in which different branches of the network are trained depending on the t_input. So the t_input can be either 0 or 1 and depending on that only the correct branch will be trained :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense

x = np.random.uniform(size=(10, 10))
t = np.random.binomial(100, 0.5)

t_input = Input(batch_shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name="t_input")
x_input = Input(shape=(x.shape[0]), name='x_input')

x = Dense(32)(x_input)

x1 = Dense(16)(x)
x1 = Dense(8)(x1)
x1 = Dense(1)(x1)

x2 = Dense(16)(x)
x2 = Dense(8)(x2)
x2 = Dense(1)(x2)

x1 = lambda: x1
x2 = lambda: x2

r = Lambda(lambda x: tf.switch_case(x, branch_fns={0: x1, 1: x2}))(t_input)

# r = tf.case([(tf.equal(t_input, 1), x1), (tf.equal(t_input, 0), x2)], default=x2, exclusive=True)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=t_input, outputs=r)

print(model.predict([1]))
```

However, I cannot make this work as it is not flexible enough to use KerasTensors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-59-92db0d55c181>", line 23, in <module>
    r = Lambda(lambda x: tf.switch_case(x, branch_fns={0: x1, 1: x2}))(t_input)
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 952, in __call__
    input_list)
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1091, in _functional_construction_call
    inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 822, in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
    return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 863, in _infer_output_signature
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 917, in call
    result = self.function(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-59-92db0d55c181>", line 23, in <lambda>
    r = Lambda(lambda x: tf.switch_case(x, branch_fns={0: x1, 1: x2}))(t_input)
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3616, in switch_case
    return _indexed_case_helper(branch_fns, default, branch_index, name)
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3326, in _indexed_case_helper
    lower_using_switch_merge=lower_using_switch_merge)
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\cond_v2.py", line 1040, in indexed_case
    op_return_value=branch_index))
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 995, in func_graph_from_py_func
    expand_composites=True)
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py", line 659, in map_structure
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py", line 659, in <listcomp>
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "C:\Users\gen06917\PycharmProjects\BaysianTarnet\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 952, in convert
    (str(python_func), type(x)))
TypeError: To be compatible with tf.eager.defun, Python functions must return zero or more Tensors; in compilation of <function <lambda> at 0x000001ED0876EAF8>, found return value of type <class 'function'>, which is not a Tensor.
```

Answer (score 1):

I got your code working by changing your tf.switch_case to a keras switch, and by inputting the two separate models in (you only input one of them in your code) Note that I had to tile your `t_test` input because it expects the two inputs to have the same batch dimension. I am also not sure that you want np.random.binomial because this samples from the binomial distribution and will almost never return 0. You should probably look at `np.random.randint` and limit it to values of 0 or 1.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense
import tensorflow.keras as K
import numpy as np

x_test = np.random.uniform(size=(10, 10))
t_test = np.array([np.random.binomial(100, 0.5)])

t_input = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int32, name="t_input")
x_input = Input(shape=(x_test.shape[1],), name='x_input')

x = Dense(32)(x_input)

x1 = Dense(16)(x)
x1 = Dense(8)(x1)
x1 = Dense(1)(x1)

x2 = Dense(16)(x)
x2 = Dense(8)(x2)
x2 = Dense(1)(x2)

r = K.backend.switch(t_input,x1,x2)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[t_input,x_input], outputs=r)

print(model.predict([np.tile(t_test,10),x_test]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to support more than 2 branches this way :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense
import tensorflow.keras as K
import numpy as np

def h_chooser(inpus):
  t_inp, h_s = inpus
  h_out = tf.squeeze(tf.concat(h_s, axis=1))
  t_inds = tf.stack([tf.range(tf.size(t_inp)), tf.squeeze(t_inp)], axis=1)
  h_res = tf.gather_nd(h_out, t_inds)
  return h_res

x_test = np.random.uniform(size=(10, 10))
t_test = np.array([np.random.binomial(100, 0.5)])

t_input = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int32, name="t_input")
x_input = Input(shape=(x_test.shape[1],), name='x_input')

x = Dense(32)(x_input)

x1 = Dense(16)(x)
x1 = Dense(8)(x1)
x1 = Dense(1)(x1)

x2 = Dense(16)(x)
x2 = Dense(8)(x2)
x2 = Dense(1)(x2)

x3 = Dense(16)(x)
x3 = Dense(8)(x3)
x3 = Dense(1)(x3)

h_switch_case = Lambda(lambda x: h_chooser(x))

r = h_switch_case([t_input, [x1, x2, x3])

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[t_input,x_input], outputs=r)

print(model.predict([np.tile(t_test,10),x_test]))
```